# How can i prevent that the jenkins log gets spammed with strange messages

Tags: jenkins

Nearly every week our development server running jenkins has no disk space left because the jenkins log file gets huge (>100g).
It gets completely filled by these strange messages:

```
[DNSQuestion@1218458593 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1577918927 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1610023624 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1936465154 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@983177141 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@229530224 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1789454415 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@2034199573 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@326302520 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1827692284 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1094138301 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1139456586 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1204101684 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@699171726 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1362017751 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@1191212370 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
    [DNSQuestion@691682052 type: TYPE_IGNORE index 0, class: CLASS_UNKNOWN index 0, name: ]
```

We are running the current Jenkins version 1.622.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a known issue with a Jenkins dependency, tracked as [JENKINS-10160](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10160) (though the issue tracker is down at the time of writing).

If you're not using the DNS service discovery features of Jenkins (which you probably aren't), then you can disable this feature with the following [command line flags](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) when starting Jenkins:

```
-Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -Dhudson.udp=-1
```

Comment: I read that it's fixed and should be released in version 1.278

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem and I used Christopher's solution which fixed the issue.
I am running jenkins on Ubuntu 14.04. I modified my /etc/default/jenkins file modifying JAVA_ARGS to

`JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -Dhudson.udp=-1"`

and then restarted jenkins